# Reload page after message is shown, jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

Right now I have a form where user enters the info. It is than processed bu jQuery ajax function and is set to `return false;` so no page reload happens after user submits a form.
Although I need to reload page, but if I remove `return false;` it refreshes page before success message is shown (this message is shown after user submits data).

```
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "scripts/process.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
       $("#st_message").html("<p> Your article was successfully added!</p>");
       //I need to reload page after the above message is shown
      }
     });
    return false;
```

So how can I reload page after the `<p> Your article was successfully added!</p>` message is shown, with a slight delay say 2 - 3 seconds, so user can actually read the message.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could add a delay by using the [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function, such as:

```
// This will reload the page after a delay of 3 seconds
window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
```

**For your needs:**

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "scripts/process.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
           $("#st_message").html("<p> Your article was successfully added!</p>");
           window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
      }
});
return false;
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dFJn8/)**

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, could it be because of return false?

Answer (score 4):

Do it with something like:

```
function delayedRedirect(){
    window.location = "/index.php"
}

setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', 3000)
```

`setTimeout` is used to delay the redirect function call, in this case you can redirect somewhere to a new URL (just in case you need that too).

Otherwise use `location.reload()` to reload page.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `setTimeout` method to get the delay, and the `reload` method to reload the page. Note the `true` parameter in the `reload` call to ensure that the page is actually reloaded, and not just repainted from the cache.

```
window.setTimeout(
  function(){
    location.reload(true)
  },
  3000
);
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, could it be because of return false?

Comment: No, that could only be a problem if you tried to reload the page immediately. Also, changing the order of the code as you noted in another comment would not make any difference. Perhaps a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like : `window.location.reload()` in JavaScript

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, could it be because of return false?

Answer (score 2):

give it using

```
setTimeout("window.location='yourpage.php'",3000);
```

in your code :

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "scripts/process.php",
       data: dataString,
       success: function() {
        $("#st_message").html("<p> Your article was successfully added!</p>");
        setTimeout("window.location='yourpage.php'",3000);//reload after 3 sec.
       }
      });
 return false;
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, could it be because of return false?

Comment: for some reason I needed to add it before $("#st_message").htm... and it now works thank you )))

Answer (score 2):

Using timeout is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "scripts/process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
  var miliseconds = 2000;

   $("#st_message").html("<p> Your article was successfully added!</p>");
   setTimeout("window.location=window.location", miliseconds);
   //I need to reload page after the above message is shown
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //
 //your action here
 //
 window.setTimeout(function(){self.parent.location="?list"},3000);//after 3 sec go to (?list or example.html page)
 return false;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

exemple :

```js
success: function(data){
            $("#loading-img").css("display","none");
                 swal({
                  title: "Félécitations",
                  text: "Votre demande a été transmise au service concerné",
                  icon: "success",
                  button: "OK",
                });
            window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true)},3000)
            }
            
            });
            return false;
            }
```